# PHP: Check if a file is loaded directly instead of including?

Tags: php, file, include

Is there a way to prevent a user viewing an file but still use it as included to another file in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you use

```
define('APP_RAN');
```

in the file that includes it and then put

```
if(!defined('APP_RAN')){ die(); }
```

or alternatively

```
defined('APP_RAN') or die();
```

(which is easier to read)

in included files it would die if you access them directly.

---

It would probably be better to put all of your included files above your DocumentRoot though.

For example, if your index page is at

```
/my/server/domain/public_html
```

You should put the included files in

```
/my/server/domain/
```

Comment: This is the best solution, it's part of basic website protection.

Comment: Which one, defining or the path?

Comment: Both, even if you can use only one.
The path is easier to implement, the define will take some time to be implemented.

Comment: `defined('APP_RAN') or die();` - agreed. Boilerplate should be as short as possible.

Comment: This is not a good solution and is outdated. Global code should be avoided in favor of namespaced code for one, but really the question can be solved programmatically without worrying about setting constants in every file that may act as an entry point. `get_included_files()[0] === __FILE__`

Comment: Also, PHP running in CLI is probably a more common use case for this which may or may not have anything to do with the web.

Answer (score 15):

My proposal:

```
<?php
if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
    exit("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\r\n<html><head>\r\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\r\n</head><body>\r\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\r\n<p>The requested URL " . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . " was not found on this server.</p>\r\n</body></html>");
}
else {
   // your code
}
?>
```

1.) it checks if it is called directly else it throws an error

2.) it outputs a 404 standard apache error page (please compare with your original 404 page or simple include that page) to add security through obscurity

3.) The else-part avoids partial execution while the file is uploaded to the live environment (PHP doesn't wait for the "?>"). You don't need it if your included file contains only one function / one class.

Comment: To support PHP hosted on both Linux and Windows, I wrapped _ _ FILE _ _ with str_replace('\\', '/', _ _ FILE _ _)

Comment: Useful in that it doesn't rely on external variables.

Answer (score 14):

```
if (!defined('FLAG_FROM_A_PARENT'))
// Works in all scenarios but I personally dislike this

if (__FILE__ == get_included_files()[0])
// Doesn't work with PHP prepend unless calling [1] instead.

if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])
// May break on Windows due to mixed DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

if (basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
// Doesn't work with files with the same basename but different paths

if (realpath(__FILE__) == realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']))
// Seems to do the trick
```

Answer (score 12):

Do not use any global code in your files, only functions and methods. Then there will be no need to care about include vs. direct use.

Comment: Agreed; if anyone manages to guess the name of your include file that has only functions and classes, all they'd see is a blank page when trying to view it.  If you're outputting html with an include (which I don't like to do) you can instead put it into a function, include the file, and call the function.

Comment: This is a good solution, but beware: if you leave your scripts in the public directory, remember to either a) make sure you don't have any syntax errors or b) turn off display errors, because otherwise they will still show up, even if the file only contains functions/classes.

Comment: I feel it should be pointed out that the technique is useful for more than just blocking direct access. Using the "needs external variable" technique, you can give a file different functionality when accessed directly. So, for example, you can easily pull in variables from post and run the primary function rather than just waiting for functions to be called and print a response, allowing you to turn it into an easy REST interface.

Answer (score 8):

Just store the file outside your web root.

Comment: Not really. From experience, some modules in some frameworks insist that your additional code be placed in specific locations, such as Laravel.

Comment: @liljoshu Yes, and frameworks like Laravel store the majority of your files ... guess where, outside the web root.

Comment: @Erik yesterday 
If you have the luxury of working on a site that was designed properly or you had the benefit of designing the site yourself, which is not always the case, that may be the case. The last Laravel I worked with had nothing outside of web root, sadly. And even then, not all files are outside of web root. Sometimes you need to work in the web root either because situation forces it or that's how a framework functions.

It's definitely _a_ good answer. Just not _the only_ good answer.

Comment: Frameworks do not have any say in where I put my code. Anything that prevents basic security measures is to be avoided.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (__FILE__ == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']){
  die("Direct access forbidden");
}
```

It works regardless of where it is. 
(Cheers to @col-sharpnel for pointing out an incomplete yet good solution.)

Comment: -1 Do not rely on PHP_SELF as this is a security vulnerability to site.com/myfile.php/badstring.php

Comment: I don't understand how this is a vulnerability. site.com/myfile.php/badstring.php simply results in a 404 error, in a simple install.

Comment: php_self is set by the agent based on the request URI. /index.php/dummy_hijack.php will not resolve /index.php. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] does. Your example is safe in a way, but not accurate. users who use basename are in trouble using PHP_SELF though. if (basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))

Comment: Okay. I get it now. Feel free to edit my post to add a warning. I don't know if I can explain it right myself.

Comment: Seems like this solution would be fine for when the program can either be included or directly accessed and you need a way to detect which method is being used.

Comment: Yep. I've added a second answer which I think is better. Yet I got no upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397004/php-check-if-a-file-is-loaded-directly-instead-of-including/23722089#23722089

Answer (score 5):

There's the [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) function. You could use it like so:

```
if ( empty(get_included_files()) ) die("Direct access forbidden");
```

Comment: Should be noted as of PHP5 this condition would never pass. See [this comment in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php#45451). The current file is always in the array, so the array always has at least 1 item ergo would never be empty. In PHP5+, one could try `if ( count(get_included_files()) === 1 ) die("Direct access forbidden");` instead.

Comment: This will work; `get_included_files()[0] === __FILE__`

Answer (score 2):

Under Apache, this is easy: add a `<Files>` directive in your .htaccess to prevent access to it from a web browser. This doesn't apply to PHP `includes`, and it is a good practice to hide several files from browser access (though usually you'll try to put all the non-accessible files together in a single directory).

```
<Files="myprivatefile.php">
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Under a different web server, you can hide the file out of your document root, but under some cases (like if your scripts are `open_basedir`'d in a strict way), it won't work.

Comment: This is the more "standard" way in most business environments that use the LAMP stack (which is where you'll see PHP the most in the business world.)

Answer (score 2):

Check how many included files are there...

```
if(count(get_required_files()) < 2) { die(); }
```

Or how many minimum there should be rather than 2

Comment: [This seems pretty foolproof, wow.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) (As long as you remember to do it, that is.)

Comment: Seems pretty good as long as the file you're putting it on doesn't require files (or you put the check above requiring the files.)

Comment: `get_included_files()[0] === __FILE__`

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for [Chacha102's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397004/php-check-if-file-is-loaded-directly-instead-of-including/2397010#2397010).

Additionally, as your question title says «*how to **check***», you can also do this without having to define a variable by using

```
// secret.php is the name of this file.
if($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=='secret.php') die();
```

Comment: This won't work as SCRIPT_FILENAME includes the complete path and not the filename only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop it from ever being displayed when not included here's a more automated way.

```
if (basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

This way it'll still work if you end up changing the file name or something.

Comment: this won't work if the included filename has the same name as the global one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($argv[0] == basename(__FILE__))
    include_once('/path/to/file.php');
```

Comment: Close but still not quite; fails when invoking from a different directory

Answer (score 1):

There are many good answers in this thread - here's one that hasn't been mentioned yet.

You can name your included PHP files with an `i` in the extension, e.g. `someincludedfile.phpi` and then configure Apache so that it doesn't serve `phpi` files. Voila.

Cons:

- (!) highly dependent on the Apache configuration (so you're vulnerable if someone neglects that line) -- and in such a event, the browser might get to see the whole PHP script in plaintext since it won't get passed off to PHP (really bad!)
- it can be annoying to rename your included files

Pros:

- makes it clear which files are to be included and which aren't in your code
- you don't have to move your file hierarchy around

Personally, I would rather just move files into a directory outside the document root, but if you have a large legacy application, this could be quicker to change.

Link: http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/21/apache-tips-tricks-deny-access-to-certain-file-types/

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the solutions with `$_SERVER` variables - below is a small .php file, and in the comments is a copy of a `bash` test I did on Ubuntu; the point being, that these variables can change quite a bit depending on the type of access, and whether symlinks are used (<sub>note also, in the code below I have to escape the '`?\>`' in the echo statement, else the syntax color breaks; remove the backslash if trying the code</sub>):

```
<?php

function report($label, $value) {
  printf ("%23s: %s\n", $label, $value);
}

report("DOCUMENT_ROOT.PHP_SELF",  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
report("SCRIPT_FILENAME",         $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
report("__FILE__",                __FILE__ );
report("PHP_SAPI",                PHP_SAPI );

/*
# the test (bash):

home~$ mkdir /tmp/ptest
home~$ cd /tmp/ptest/
ptest$ ln -s /real/path/to/varcheck.php .
ptest$ echo '<? require_once "varcheck.php"; ?\>' > varcheckincl.php


# ... and in a separate terminal, run
# php (>5.4) cli server at same (/tmp/ptest) location:

ptest$ php-5.4.10 -S localhost:8000

# back to first terminal, the test - and output:

ptest$ php varcheck.php
 DOCUMENT_ROOT.PHP_SELF: varcheck.php
        SCRIPT_FILENAME: varcheck.php
               __FILE__: /real/path/to/varcheck.php
               PHP_SAPI: cli

ptest$ php -r 'require_once "varcheck.php";'
 DOCUMENT_ROOT.PHP_SELF: -
        SCRIPT_FILENAME:
               __FILE__: /real/path/to/varcheck.php
               PHP_SAPI: cli

ptest$ php varcheckincl.php
 DOCUMENT_ROOT.PHP_SELF: varcheckincl.php
        SCRIPT_FILENAME: varcheckincl.php
               __FILE__: /real/path/to/varcheck.php
               PHP_SAPI: cli

ptest$ wget http://localhost:8000/varcheck.php -q -O -
 DOCUMENT_ROOT.PHP_SELF: /tmp/ptest/varcheck.php
        SCRIPT_FILENAME: /tmp/ptest/varcheck.php
               __FILE__: /real/path/to/varcheck.php
               PHP_SAPI: cli-server

ptest$ wget http://localhost:8000/varcheckincl.php -q -O -
 DOCUMENT_ROOT.PHP_SELF: /tmp/ptest/varcheckincl.php
        SCRIPT_FILENAME: /tmp/ptest/varcheckincl.php
               __FILE__: /real/path/to/varcheck.php
               PHP_SAPI: cli-server
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @HelpNeeder's post here. Will work regardless of directory or context.

```
// if we called this file directly, then we are using stdout
if (get_included_files()[0] === __FILE__) {

    /** @noinspection PhpUnhandledExceptionInspection */
    print json_encode($deploymentMatrix, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

} else {

    return $deploymentMatrix;

}
```