# PHP script detect that it is an include

Tags: include, php

I have a PHP class file that is used as an include both through a web server and by a cron process. I am looking for a way to add some code to the head of the script so that I can detect if the script is being launched directly from the command line instead of being included in another script. This way I can make testing a bit easier by calling the script directly and having a function instantiate the object and execute some code on it without needing to create a wrapper script for it.

I tried using `if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {` but that tests true even if the script is being included in another script that was called from the command line.

Comment: This is a duplicate.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397004/php-check-if-file-is-loaded-directly-instead-of-including for an answer.  There are a few valid ones.

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate, the other question is different.

Comment: Isn't that more about detecting (and preventing) direct access through Apache, rather than what I want to do, detecting and performing additional operations when the file is directly accessed at the command line?

Comment: exactly. Your question is definitely not a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the presence of [`$argv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php). If `$argv[0]` is set (the script name), your script is run from the command line.

Comment: Won't this still test true if the script is included by another script that was called from the command line? Although I could check the value of $argv[0] if it is set... Hm...

Comment: @Wige It´s a global variable so if your script is called from another script that is run from the command line, it will still exist.

Comment: This looks like the closest solution so far. What seems to work at the moment is `if (isset($argv[0]) && strpos($argv[0], 'file.class.php') > 0) {` This method seems to be the best to always detect if the file is being called directly from the command line.

Comment: @Wige Yes, you´ll have to add a second if the script that includes it can also be run from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Checking that $argv[0] is set lets you know if things were invoked from the command line; it does not tell you if the file was invoked directly or if it was included from another file. To determine that, test if `realpath($argv[0]) == realpath(__FILE__)`.

Putting it all together:

```
if (isset($argv[0]) && realpath($argv[0]) == realpath(__FILE__))
    // This file was called directly from command line
```

Comment: This is the real answer. `$argv[0]` will be set on both the file that's being called through the cli and scripts that will be included by that script. But on all scripts `$argv[0]` will be set with the same filename, the one that's being directly called. `__FILE__ != $argv[0]` on included/required scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could test if `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is empty. It will be empty in the command line execution since it's a variable predefined by apache.

What's interesting is `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is defined but empty. I would have guessed it wouldn't be defined at all when using the cli.

You could also test if `$argv` is defined or its size (at least 1 when using CLI). I didn't test when including the file but if defined, `sizeof($argv)`would definitely be 0.

Other possible tests are `$_SERVER['argc']` (0 when executed by a server, 1 when executed from CLI) and a strange `$_SERVER['_']` defined to the path to the PHP binary, which is not defined at all when served.

To conclude, I would rely on `$_SERVER['argc']` (or `$argc`) which is a direct count of the number of arguments passed to the command line: will always be 0 when the script is served. Relying on $argv is more complicated: you have to test if `$argv[0]` is set or if `sizeof($argv)` is > 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used `if (defined('STDIN'))` as such a check.  `STDIN` will be defined if the script is run from a shell, but not if it's in a server environment.

As you can see here and at the link Ryan provided in his comment, there are lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']==__FILE__){
   // Directly
}else{
   // Included
}
```

Comment: When answering, it's recommended to share some context instead of just posting a snippet. [Check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write an answer.