# How to find out a php file is included or accessed directly?

Tags: php

Is there any way to find out if a php script is accessed directly or it's included.

1. Suppose we don't where it's included, so setting session variable won't solve the problem. I can not check where it's included. it may be more than 20 places!
2. It should be detected in php script. (via php functions and variables)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397004/php-check-if-a-file-is-loaded-directly-instead-of-including

Comment: [List your includes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) and [Prevent Direct Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file)

Comment: no it's not duplicate, see point 1 of my question, I can not check where it's included. it may be more than 20 places!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if(__FILE__ != $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) {
  // we're in an include
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Used ceejayoz's answer but I have troubles when using symlinked files and paths due to `__FILE__` being resolved to the real path automatically. So I used `realpath()` function on `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` instead to resolve both paths to the real path to solve the problem.

```
if(__FILE__ != realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
    // we're in an include
}
```