# I want a php file to be displayed only when used in include or require. Is it possible?

Tags: php

I am using a common file called `menubar.php` which obviously shows menubar. I am using `REQUIRE("menubar.php")` in all the files which need menubar to be shown. The problem I am facing is I don't want the menubar to be displayed if I am accessing it through url ex. `localhost/project/menubar.php`.

Comment: Do you want to browse this menubar.php file via url like localhost/project/menubar.php.? Or do you want to prevent to access this file via direct url?

Comment: Just store the file in a directory above your web root directory.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to know what to look for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397004/php-check-if-a-file-is-loaded-directly-instead-of-including

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent direct access to a php include file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409496/prevent-direct-access-to-a-php-include-file)

Comment: improve code output

Answer (score 0):

That is how I prevented direct access from URL to your menubar.php file. Paste the following code in .htaccess file inside the directory where 'menubar.php' file is located.

```
<Files ~ "menubar.php">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

It will prevent to access menubar.php file via url, but it can access inside your server language.

Comment: There is no guarantee this is an Apache type server, or that the server config will allow this.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion jino shaji. What I did instead was used session. In menubar.php i am using a session variable but I did not write session_start(). I write session_start where i need the menubar then require 'menubar.php'. This way the menubar.php only executes when it was called by a php page having session_start()