# How i hide direct access to file

Tags: php

How set direct access to php file 
I use fancybox to send function "You got new message", and i  have newmessage.php on server and  i want to hide this newmessage.php when user go to test.com/newmessage.php  show messsage no direct access to file ?

If user got new message show newmessage.php function on fancybox ...
I try this but when is open fancybox and i get no direct access to file ...

```
if(!defined('MyConst')) {
 die('Direct access not permitted');
}
```

Comment: just put your `newmessage.php` outside the root folder, and no one will access it directly, but you will be able to include it like: `../newmessage.php`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Check if a file is loaded directly instead of including?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397004/php-check-if-a-file-is-loaded-directly-instead-of-including)

Comment: With "fancybox" I suppose you mean it loads a URL either in an iframe, or fetches the HTML from it and puts it in a popup…?

Comment: so i do this i moved newmessage.php out of public_html to **etc/my-site/newmessage.php** there my function, now how i can call this function on index.php  i try this `define("BASE_URL", "/etc");
define("ROOT_PATH", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/etc");
echo "<a id=\"version\" href='".BASE_URL."/my-site/newmessage.php'>test</a>` but i cant get info .... any help ?